# Android create a text file on internal storage, email it, then delete the file

Tags: android, bufferedwriter, internal-storage

I want to be able to create a text file with data inside of it, email that file, and then get rid of it on my Android device.

Below is what I have so far but it is giving me the error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /20150719_130219: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)
```

Code:

```
 BufferedWriter writer = null;
    try {
        //create a temporary file
        String report = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        File logFile = new File(report);

        writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(logFile));
        for (Map.Entry entry : cbh.data.entrySet()) {
            reportText.append(entry.getKey() + ", " + entry.getValue() + "\n");
            writer.write(entry.getKey() + ", " + entry.getValue() + "\n");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            writer.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to provide permissions in your manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Second in your code you are just generating the name of the file but its complete path is not defined where it will be saved.

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
```

will return the path of sdcard

You can write this

```
String report = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
String fileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ report+".txt";
File file = new File(fileName);
```

Comment: Instead of moving to external storage you could have stayed with OP's wisch to use internal storage. For internal storage use getFilesDir(). You don't need any permission for it.